# Is this correct in matching?

Tags: regex, linux, shell, awk, pattern-matching

The following code works to get the status value of `a` if its enabled, `d` if its disabled and `n` if its not present from a file given below:

```
# Check whether the service entry exists and whether it is enabled or disabled
# Status value 'a' states that the service is uncommented in /etc/inetd.conf.
# Value 'd' states that the service is commented, and value 'n' specifies
# that the service entry doesnt exist in the configuration file.
status=`awk -v serv=$1 -v proto=$2 -v exist="n" '
        BEGIN {
        format=sprintf("^[\t ]*%s.*%s",serv,proto);
        comformat=sprintf("^[\t ]*#[\t ]*%s.*%s",serv,proto);
        }
        {
        if(match($0,format))
        {
                exist="a";
        }
        else if(match($0,comformat))
        {
                exist="d";
        }
        }
        END {
        printf("%s",exist)
        }' $INETD`
```

From the following file:

```
ftp     stream  tcp6    nowait  root    /usr/sbin/ftpd         ftpd
telnet  stream  tcp6    nowait  root    /usr/sbin/telnetd      telnetd -a
shell   stream  tcp6    nowait  root    /usr/sbin/rshd         rshd
#kshell  stream  tcp     nowait  root    /usr/sbin/krshd        krshd
login   stream  tcp6    nowait  root    /usr/sbin/rlogind      rlogind
#klogin  stream  tcp     nowait  root    /usr/sbin/krlogind     krlogind
```

Note: `$1` =  column 1 in the file and `$2` = column 3 in file.

So my concern is if the above searching using the following format good enough? or is there anyother better regular expression:

```
 format=sprintf("^[\t ]*%s.*%s",serv,proto);
 comformat=sprintf("^[\t ]*#[\t ]*%s.*%s",serv,proto);
```

Comment: You will have a problem if you have two services named, say, "service" and "service2": your regexes will match both.

Comment: What is the alternative? Rather the correct way to do it?

Comment: Well, I don't know awk, but you already have it split the fields for you. If I were you, I'd check for equality of the first field with either "$service" or "#$service".

Comment: What's the use of `$2 (i.e column3)`?

Comment: @JaypalSingh it tells which protocol to use. IPv4/6

Comment: True, but we are not using it to verify anything, the condition is only based on the presence of `#` tag in front of the first column. If it is present we capture `d`, if not then `a` and if service is not there then `n`. Isn't it? Or may be I misunderstood the question?

Comment: @JaypalSingh your confusion is right. I havent mentioned that its part of a larger file. We can have different versions of the same column-1 entry. Like ftp tcp6 & ftp tcp  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I have understood of the problem this might work -

```
status=$(awk -v serv="$1" -v proto="$2" '
$1==serv && $3==proto {val="a";exit}
$1=="#"serv && $3==proto {val="d";exit}
END{if ((val=="a") || (val=="d")) print val; else print "n"}' $INETD)
```

**Test:** Based on passing the values manually and using the below content in file

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat f1
ftp     stream  tcp6    nowait  root    /usr/sbin/ftpd         ftpd
telnet  stream  tcp6    nowait  root    /usr/sbin/telnetd      telnetd -a
shell   stream  tcp6    nowait  root    /usr/sbin/rshd         rshd
#kshell  stream  tcp     nowait  root    /usr/sbin/krshd        krshd
login   stream  tcp6    nowait  root    /usr/sbin/rlogind      rlogind
#klogin  stream  tcp     nowait  root    /usr/sbin/krlogind     krlogind

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -v serv="kshell" -v proto="tcp" ' # kshell exists but is commented
$1==serv && $3==proto {val="a";exit}
$1=="#"serv && $3==proto {val="d";exit}
END{if ((val=="a") || (val=="d")) print val; else print "n"}' f1
d
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -v serv="ftp" -v proto="tcp6" ' # tcp6 proto exits
$1==serv && $3==proto {val="a";exit}
$1=="#"serv && $3==proto {val="d";exit}
END{if ((val=="a") || (val=="d")) print val; else print "n"}' f1
a
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -v serv="ftp" -v proto="tcp" ' # tcp proto does not exist
$1==serv && $3==proto {val="a";exit}
$1=="#"serv && $3==proto {val="d";exit}
END{if ((val=="a") || (val=="d")) print val; else print "n"}' f1
n
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a space after each string to avoid the problem seen by @fge. In particular, without it, you would match "tcp" if "tcp6" is in the file.

```
format=sprintf("^[\t ]*%s[\t ].*%s[\t ]",serv,proto);
comformat=sprintf("^[\t ]*#[\t ]*%s[\t ].*%s[\t ]",serv,proto);
```

Using a big BEGIN block is not very idiomatic AWK but it's maybe the solution with a pattern coming from outside like that.

If your AWK implementation supports POSIX regexp, you can also use the '[:space:]' class to match more kink of whitespaces (='[ \t\r\n\v\f]')